# How to replace a domain\username in xml using powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to replace a node which has domainname\username.

As it has "\" it fails in regular expression match,

> Invalid regular expression pattern: l8-dc\testuser2. At
>   C:\Users\testuser1.l8-dc\Desktop\RunTimeAccountChange\UserAccount-Replace.ps1:164
>   char:68
>   +                             $Searchstr.Node.'#text'= $($Searchstr.Node.'#text') -replace <<<<  $OldUserName,$NewUserN ame
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (l4-dc\mesuser2:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression

The following line fails actually..

```
$Searchstr.Node.'#text'= $($Searchstr.Node.'#text') -replace $OldUserName,$NewUserName
```

How to replace with regular expression match?

Comment: If the regular expression is failing, don't you think it might be wise to add the regular expression to your question? It's hard to help you fix it when you don't let us see where it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to see the actual regex pattern to be sure, but I'm guessing that you need to escape a \ somewhere in it. Do this by adding another \ to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Searchstr.Node.'#text'= $($Searchstr.Node.'#text') -replace $($OldUserName),$($NewUserName)
```

If this doesn't work, you can try to change the script just a little to look like this:

```
$Domain = "MyDomain"
$OldUserName = "OldUser"
$NewUserName = "NewUesr"
$Searchstr.Node.'#text'= $($Searchstr.Node.'#text') -replace $($Domain + "\" + $OldUserName),$($Domain + "\" + $NewUserName)
```

I do the second one in my environment a lot, but that's because we have many test decks that are all different domains, but with the same usernames across.